# Identify POM type dependencies programmatically in java for gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, pom.xml

I am trying to read the output of “gradle dependencies” and i have noticed that it does not provide us with the type information that maven does.

So for example maven dependencies shows us this : where we can get the type of dependencies be it jar/ejb/ war/ pom ,etc

```
[**INFO**] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[**INFO**] | +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
```

However the output of  gradle dependencies we only get something like this

```
+--- org.lunarray.model:bom:1.0
|    +--- org.lunarray.common:base:1.0
|    |    \--- org.lunarray.common:bom:1.0
```

I was taking a look at DefaultArtifactResolutionQuery but it seems like it requires a lot of parameters in constructor that i dont totally understand.

So my question is : given a group artifact version, how do i identify whether its a pom type, jar type, ejb type, etc dependency programmatically in java?

Tried using ArtifactResolutionQUery but not able to figure out usage

Answer (score 0):

From the Gradle CLI, you can obtain additional information using the `dependencyInsight` query:

> `./gradlew [submodule:]dependencyInsight --dependency=<dependency name> --configuration=runtimeClasspath`

Note this is restricted via `--configuration`.  If you don't add this, it prints it for every configuration, which results in a very large output from the `dependencies` task.

You get something like this:

```
com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.42.3 (by constraint)
  Variant runtime:
    | Attribute Name                 | Provided     | Requested    |
    |--------------------------------|--------------|--------------|
    | org.gradle.status              | release      |              |
    | org.gradle.category            | library      | library      |
    | org.gradle.libraryelements     | jar          | jar          |
    | org.gradle.usage               | java-runtime | java-runtime |
    | org.gradle.dependency.bundling |              | external     |
    | org.gradle.jvm.environment     |              | standard-jvm |
    | org.gradle.jvm.version         |              | 17           |

// ...  And then a bunch more info
```

But, you asked about "programmatically in Java".  I'm interpolating your request here, because I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for.  Gradle is in either Groovy or Kotlin, unless you're authoring a plugin or some such.  That said, perhaps if provided with a Groovy answer, a Java variant, it would provide insight on where you could look.

This Gradle task does print out the dependencies, along with the "attributes" property, which flags BOM dependencies.  There are many other properties, as well as `metaPropertyValues`, which duplicate many of the properties.  But, for the purpose of detecting a bom or whatnot, this does the trick.

Note, this is also restricted via the `runtimeClasspath` configuration.  You could enumerate configurations and iterate over them, but this was simply for an example.

```
tasks.register('readOut') {
    configurations.named("runtimeClasspath") {
        it.allDependencies.each {
            println "- " + it.name + ", " + it.getGroup() + ":" + it.getName() + ":" + it.getVersion() + " " + it.properties['attributes']
        }
    }
}
```

It prints out something like this:

```
- my-bom, com.example:my-bom:1.1.0 {org.gradle.category=platform}
- some-other-package, net.example:some-other-package:1.1.0 {}    
- log4j-core, org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.19.0 {}                          
- log4j-api, org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.19.0 {}
```

The formatting is unimportant here, but it demonstrates that it is capturing the additional properties programmatically, which would allow for automation.

Comment: well dependencyinsight prints jar as  org.gradle.libraryelements for everything, irrespective of whether its a pom import or not. i am actually parsing the output of gradle dependencies in java side to find out dependency map for a project. this is where i need the information whether a dependency is a pom or a normal one. pretty simple in maven. oh and i also cant make any changes in build.gradle file :(